# Eclipse EGit can't commit source, can only commit bin

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm using Eclipse EGit with a bitbucket.org repo to develop a Minecraft mod with a friend. When I right click the project and click commit, it only lets me commit files from the bin folder. If I right click the src folder in Eclipse, the commit option is grayed out.

How can I get EGit to let me commit my source files?

I ended up working around this by using Eclipse's built-in Git functionality, which was hard to discover that Eclipse even had, as the first search result for "using git with eclipse" is EGit.

Comment: Have you looked at any EGit documentation? If so, what did you find?

Comment: I wasn't able to find very much documentation. I found nothing covering the issue I was experiencing.

Comment: Weird problem. Where is the root of your git repository? And what is the contents of your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: The .gitignore was initially empty, I later added the bin folder to it, because the src folder was all I really wanted. I tried putting creating the repo in the root of my Eclipse workspace as well as creating the repo in a completely different directory, neither seemed to help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you didn't press 'add index' on src folder. and make sure src is not in .ignore text file.

Comment: It was not in the .gitignore file. I saw no "add index" option for the src folder. In the commit window, it did not even show any files in the src folder.